# Cloud Firestore Custom Claims when null

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am blocking users by adding to their token using cloud functions

```
exports.blockUser = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {

const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data['email']);

if(context.auth.token.admin){
    admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        block: true
    });
    console.log(data['email'] + " has been blocked");
    return 1;
}else{

    return 2;

}});
```

In my rules i have set to allow read if block == null, because users that are not blocked will not have that data on their token.

```
allow read: if request.auth.token.block == null;
```

However this does not work and permission is denied.

I have tried the other way round just to ensure that the token data exist

```
allow read: if request.auth.token.block == true;
```

This allowed only block users to be able to read data. and it work. which means there is no issue with the data on the token.

What can i do to allow users which dont have the "block" property on their token to be able to read data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With security rules, a missing property is not the same as the property equating to null.  You should instead check to see if the block property actually exists, and also check if its value should restrict access

```
allow read: if !("block" in request.auth.token) || equest.auth.token.block == false;
```

Reference the documentation for [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) (`request.auth.token` is a Map).